# RxJs BehaviorSubject's next() method in service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I use the following approach in order to refresh `Details` page after a new record added. I also need to refresh after updating a record as well.

***EventProxyService***

```
export class EventProxyService {
    private eventTracker = new BehaviorSubject<any>();

    getEvent(): Observable<any> {
        return this.eventTracker.asObservable();
    }

    setEvent(param: any): void {
        this.eventTracker.next(param);
    }
}
```

***CreateComponent:***

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private eventProxyService: EventProxyService) { }

    create(param: any): void {
        //other staff related to creating record

        this.eventProxyService.setEvent(param);
    }
}
```

***DetailsComponent:***

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    subscription;

    constructor(private eventProxyService: EventProxyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.eventProxyService.getEvent().subscribe((param: any) => {
            this.refresh(param);
        );
    }

    refresh(param) {
        this.record = param; //update record via new one passed from service
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

The approach works well but I am a little bit confused regarding to the following issues:

**1)** Because I also call `this.eventProxyService.setEvent(param);` in `update()` method like in `create()` method, would it be good idea to call this in my service level instead of component level?

**2)** Is there anything wrong when firing next() method in  `CreateComponent` above?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first question. But to answer the second question, your BehaviorSubject is private, so you would not be able to call it from the component. It's a good idea for the BehaviorSubject to be private to the service to ensure that no other code modifies it.

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks for reply. Actually first question mentioned that *what if I call the setEvent() in the create() method of my service (not this proxyService, I meant other service where I keep my CRUD methods)?* Any idea?

Comment: @DeborahK For the second question, I asked that *I call the next() via setEvent() method in the CRUD methods, after create, update, delete operations are completed. Is it a good approach, it is there a better way in real world examples e.g. calling next() in the service (CRUD) as I asked in the first question.* Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is pretty much fine with **[`BehaviourSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)** (at least in my prospective).

One thing I can advice is try **`BehaviourSubject`** in the singleton service. (which I can't notice in your case)

> what if I call the setEvent() in the create() method of my service (not this proxyService, I meant other service where I keep my CRUD
> methods)

If I Understood your question properly, Answer is NO.

Because calling a service method from another service is not advisable, So keep things simple. In real world projects once the CRUD methods gets executed then we will try to refresh the data from the component itself with the help of service methods (but not in the service).

> I call the next() via setEvent() method in the CRUD methods, after create, update, delete operations are completed. Is it a good
> approach, it is there a better way in real world examples e.g. calling
> next() in the service (CRUD) as I asked in the first question

Yes, it is a good approach.

Comment: What about using a single subscription as mentioned on [Using a single subscription variable with BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562345/using-a-single-subscription-variable-with-behaviorsubject)? Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think your current approach is totally valid. You could consider adding restriction rules, like you already mentioned, to just call `setEvent` from your service layer. This would improve the single responsibility of your component. Anyway I think this really depends on the size and the lifetime of your project. For beginning a project so would definitely do it the same way you did!

Comment: Thanks for reply. **1)** If you use BehaviorSubject in your apps, what do you in in real world projects? Do you call next (here setEvent() method) from Controller's CRUD method (create(), update(), etc) after CRUD operation done? **2)** On the other hand, if I call the next() in the Component level, for example create() method, I will have to call the next() for each create()  method calls. For this reason I think of calling next() on service (crud) level (create method in the service that is called from the create method in the Component). Any idea?